# .htaccess folder and file name conflict in url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess to allow for no file extensions in the url:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

My problem is that i have both a file called images.php and a folder called images, so when i use the url: .com/images - it takes me to the images folder, where as: .com/contact - takes me to the correct page.

Comment: where take you ...com/images/  ?

Comment: And you said you've tried removing the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`?

Comment: Hey there I have the same problem, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I am also having this problem. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

With these 2 lines, you say if the test string (in your case 'images') is not a directory and is not a file, rewrite it to images.php. Now, since you have images directory, the second rule is not satisfied and images is rewriten to images.php internaly.

Either change the name of the folder, change the name of the script, or change the .htaccess rules and conditions.

Comment: What would i change the htacces conditions to? I have tried every combination of -f and -d with removing them and reversing them(!) and still it looks for the folder first

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add before your rule this rule suppose to work ...(but  I didn't test it)

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$    images/$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Tim Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366234/tim-stone) suggested, removing the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` line will fix the problem.

Your rules should then look as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```